# Accurate method for measuring iron core size

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Does anyone know a simple and accurate way to measure the size of an iron core using a magnetic sensor?

Imagine having a collection of identical iron plates. I expect the strength of the magnetic field around the core to increase with its size.

Would it be possible to determine the number of stacked plates by measuring the magnetic field strength using e.g. a Hall effect sensor placed on top of the staple? Are there better sensors/methods?